# HTTPS for each EC2 instance in an Auto Scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate

How can you setup HTTPS for each individual EC2 instance in an Auto Scaling group?

Usually a load balancer in front of the group would handle this by holding an SSL/TLS certificate, but in my architecture there is no load balancer; instead clients query a directory service which provides them the IP address of an instance (instances notify the directory of their existence via a redis server's pub/sub functionality). Consequently the EC2 instances themselves have to carry SSL/TLS certificates. Since this is an Auto Scaling group, instances could pop in/out of existence at any time so certificates cannot be assigned manually. I know AWS can assign each instance a default public IP address from their pool, as well as a generic DNS name like ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com, but they don't come with a certificate.

So, how do I get these instances to have certificates given that their default DNS name is as good as random? I'm thinking maybe I could somehow set them up under a custom parent domain and have each instance claim a unique subdomain at will, thereby allowing them to use a wildcard certificate that covers the parent domain, but I'm not quite sure how that's done.

Comment: Why are you not using an ELB with your AutoScaling group? This takes care of everything for you, including directing the requests to the instances, and dramatically simplifies your processes; you may not even need to query that directory service and/or Redis because the ELB will be static and requests can simply go direct there - the ELB could actually save you $.

Comment: If you continue in your current architecture, you'll need to get your own certificate and make sure it's installed every time a new instance is launched with the ASG, then you'll b) need to setup an internal DNS and update that DNS to point to the specific instance every time a new instance launches and claims a new domain, c) you'll need to update your "pointers" in the directory and Redis that point to the old, and new, domains so that they resolve correctly when queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t use Amazons ACM certificates on EC2 instances. You‘ll have to provide your own certificate. e.g. a wildcard certificate which is valid for *.example.com. Then you assign subdomains to your instances in Route53 and save those in your Redis database.

I don‘t recommend to use custom machine images which will cause a huge maintenance overhead on the long run.

Setup machines at launch time using launch scripts or more professional with Opsworks where you can utilize the power of chef or puppet to setup and run your service.
https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/

**edit, clarifying route53 usage**

Either in the instance registration routine
or when using opsworks in the configure or deploy event receipe you can utilize the AWS Route53 API to create a subdomain, e.g the instance name. The number of subdomains is not limited as far as I know.

More details about opsworks events https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-events.html

More details about Route53 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

Comment: **you assign subdomains to your instances in Route53**
This is the part I don't understand since I've never used Route53 before. Can they ask Route53 for a subdomain when they spin up? Does Route53 need to have a set of predefined subdomains to choose from or can they be computed incrementally?

Comment: Updated answer with some more details

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create custom AMI for your launch configuration.
2. In that you have to configured your SSL certificate .
3. Whenever your instance will launch that will come up with SSL.
4. and which ever application are you running for that you have to write rewrite rule.
   **for example Nginx http to https redirection.**

> ```
> server {
>            listen         80;
>            server_name    www.example.org;
>            rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
>         }
>
>         server {
>            listen         1443;
>            server_name    www.example.org;
>        }
> ```